# Calling a function from another script [REACT NATIVE]

Tags: typescript, react-native, function

For my bachelor project, I am developing a chat application in react native, while learning the framework. It is almost done, but I have one issue that I could use some help with.
On my homescreen I have a list of all the chat rooms that the user has joined. On the homescreen script i have the following function, which adds a chat to the list.

```
  const handleAddChat = (id: string, name: string) => {
const newChat = { id, name };
setChatItems([...chatItems, newChat]);
setChat('');
```

}

I also have a "create chat room" screen, with a seperate script. The user can create a chat room, and on the press of a button, that chat room should get added to the list on the homescreen. So i need to be able to call handleAddChat from my create chat room screen, which has a separate script.

How would I do that? I am using typescript.